# phpBB - login NOT case sensitive

Tags: php, phpbb

How can you make the username case insensitive, and give the possibility to login with both email and username?

can't seem to find anything under administration.. is it possible to change in the cms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, change the login query to

```
$emailOrUser = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['emailorusername']);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string(phpBB_password_hash_function($_POST['password']));

$loggedIn = mysql_query("...
                        where (email = '" . $emailOrUser . "' or lowercase(username) = '" . strtolower($emailOrUser) . "') 
                        and (password = '" . $password . "')");
```

Or if you can't or don't want to program, take a look [here](http://www.phpbb.com/customise/db/mod/prime_login_via_email/) since it's a freely downloadable mod for phpBB that lets you login with email.

You can also change the user table to a case-insensitive collation, but that might produce unexpectable results, just as my query. I don't know whether phpBB lets you create two accounts if the casing differs (user vs USER, are that two different valid accounts?).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try with a filter of some sort (filter the imput).